# How to add value of some specify row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
user_id  report_date  tBalance  yBalance                 total_purchase_amt 
     3     20131106         0         0                   0   
     4     20131106         0         0                  5119808
```

such as I have a DataFrame like this, I want to add the value of tBalance, yBalance in row 1 and row 2 together when report_date is 20131106

Comment: Your question makes little sense, what value? what is the desired output?

Comment: Are your dates strings or ints here? Is this what you're after: `df.loc[df['report_date'] == 20131106, ['tBalance','yBalance']].sum()`?

Comment: This should work then: `df.loc[df['report_date'] == '20131106', ['tBalance','yBalance']].sum()` but what are you trying to do as this code snippet is for a specifc value

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `groupby` for this

```
df_summary = df.groupby('report_date').sum()
```

Let assume that your dataframe `df' is

```
   user_id  report_date  tBalance  yBalance  total_purchase_amt 
0        3     20131106         0         0                    0
1        4     20140726         0         0              5119808
2        5     20131106       153       153                    0
```

(Just modified your data little bit, so that first and last report date are same)

when you do

```
> df.groupby('report_date').sum()
             user_id  tBalance  yBalance  total_purchase_amt 
report_date                                                  
20131106           8       153       153                    0
20140726           4         0         0              5119808
```

`.sum()` will add up all numeric columns and ignore non-numeric columns. Or you can filter only those required columns before doing `groupby`

Comment: is this what you are expecting??

Comment: Yes,It is exactly what I expected